# Double LEFT JOIN with same tables

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

My sql:

```
SELECT * FROM ex_pair
LEFT JOIN ex_currency as client
ON client_curr = currency_id
LEFT JOIN ex_currency as company
ON co_curr = currency_id
```

I need to get data for two currency_id but I have an error

> ambiguous column name: 'currency_id'

Is there any way to do it right or i need to use two queries?

Comment: Post your schema.

Comment: You need to qualify the column name of the table you need it from, so you would have `(tableName).currency_id`, where `tableName` is the table where you need `currency_id` from.

Comment: It's a good habit to get into to alias each table when joining, and reference each table with that alias everywhere, even if the column is not ambiguous. It avoids errors like this and makes it easier to read for people who may not be familiar with the table structure. For example in your query, currency_id or client_curr could have been in either table of the join, though common sense does say currency_id is in the ex_currency table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your alias in your join, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ex_pair
LEFT JOIN ex_currency AS client
ON client_curr = client.currency_id
LEFT JOIN ex_currency as company
ON co_curr = company.currency_id
```

You may also want to do something other than select * as you will have two tables with the same columns - something like

```
SELECT pair.*, company.currency_id AS company_currency_id, client.currency_id as client_currency_id, [...]
FROM ex_pair AS pair
[...]
```

This way when you explicitly declare the columns you intend to use from ex_currency with an alias, you can know on the other end more easily which are client and which are company. You will need to do this for each column in the currency table that you want in your result, though that can be done if you have your table structure in your code easily enough by looping over the list of columns and appending the alias.

```
$array = [
    1=> "currency_id",
    2=> "currency_name"
];

$columns = ""
foreach($array as $column){
    $columns.= "company.".$column." AS company_".$column;
    $columns.= ",client.".$column." AS client_".$column.",";
}

$columns = rtrim($columns,',');
```

Gives you

`company.currency_id AS company_currency_id,client.currency_id AS client_currency_id,company.currency_name AS company_currency_name,client.currency_name AS client_currency_name`

Add that after your `SELECT pair.*` and you get your columns from the currency table, aliased so you know which is which.

Comment: Whatever columns are in your ex_currency table, the names go in `$array`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the alias that you give to the tables:

```
SELECT client.currency_id as client_currency, company.currency_id as company_currency
FROM ex_pair 
LEFT JOIN ex_currency as client ON client_curr = client.currency_id
LEFT JOIN ex_currency as company ON co_curr = company.currency_id
```

Comment: While aliasing the columns is a good idea, this excludes the columns from ex_pair, and only shows the ID field from the currency table, if that's all they wanted then `SELECT client_curr as client_currency, co_curr as company_currency FROM ex_pair` is better since it only needs the one table.